# Building your own ESP8266 development board

Tags: esp8266

I was wondering if someone could help me out?

I have been looking for a project that would test my existing skills and force me to learn new ones, and I thought that trying to build my own ESP8266 development board might be the best thing for me to try out.

I got some ESP 12-F boards and some veroboards that support it, it has a space for the ESP-12 and pads that lead to holes you can solder to.

However, I am a little confused at the moment. On a NodeMCU, for instance, you have way more connections than the ESP 12 offers out of the box. Is there a resource or guide that explains how these are broken out so that I can figure out how to provide those connections on my little dev board project? Like on the example here:

https://randomnerdtutorials.com/getting-started-with-esp8266-wifi-transceiver-review/

I get that I need to add the UART logic, I have that on order right now. I am just confused at the moment on how to break out the rest of the pins.

I hope this makes sense, please be gentle on me, this really is my first serious project and I wanted it to be challenging in order to learn.

Cheers,

Rafa

Comment: on esp-12 the esp8266 with external flash and supporting circuit is under the metallic cover. NodeMCU has pins which can't be used because the quad SPI for external flash uses them. these pins could be shared only with some SPI devices. the example for this sharing is for LCD.

Comment: Take a look at the NodeMCU [schematic diagram](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0/blob/master/NODEMCU_DEVKIT_V1.0.PDF) and compare to ESP-12F module pinout, you will see the differences.